# ¿Cómo puedo descargar 2 archivos distintos utilizando el procedimiento HTTP protocol en genexus 17u2?

Tags: genexus

Les traigo una consulta sobre cómo lograr, por medio de un procedimiento HTTP, que Genexus me descargue 2 archivos diferentes.

**HERRAMIENTA:** GeneXus 17u2

**REQUERIMIENTO:** Descargar 2 archivos independientes por medio de protocolo HTTP, ya que son mutuamente excluyentes.

**PROBLEMA:** El procedimiento que ejecuta el protocolo http de descarga funciona correctamente, pero se ejecuta una sola vez, no descargando el segundo archivo. Se comprobó que los archivos descargados de manera individual funcionan correctamente.

**POSIBLES SOLUCIONES (NO FUNCIONARON):**

- Crear un procedimiento http individual por cada archivo a descargar.
- Ejecutar por medio de 2 funciones (Sub) el mismo procedimiento utilizando diferentes variables.
- Se utiliza Chrome como navegador por defecto. No se puede cambiar la política de permitir descargar más de un archivo de la misma fuente debido a que esta se controla por el depto. de Seguridad.
- Se utilizó otro navegador (Edge), con los mismos resultados.

**CÓDIGO DE MUESTRA:**

```
Sub 'U_BotonClic'
//Boton para ejecutar el procedimiento de transformacion y descarga de archivos
do 'Convertir'
endsub

sub 'convertir'
//Metodo para escribir un archivo de texto (ASCII) luego de utilizar datos cargados a un archivo blob; funciona correctamente
if (&validacion = 1)
do 'registroIncluido'
else
do 'registroExcluido'
endif
do 'descargarArchivoIncluido' //Metodo que invoca al procedimiento de archivos incluidos
do 'descargarArchivoExcluido' //Metodo que invoca al procedimiento de archivos excluidos
endsub

sub 'registroIncluido'
&FileNameI = "ARCHIVOINCLUIDO.ASC" //Nombre que tendra el archivo de texto
&FileNameIPath = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &FileNameI //El archivo se guardara en el directorio de archivos temporales de windows
&I = DFWOPEN(&FileNameIPath, "", "", 1, "")
&I = DFWPTXT(&RegistrosI)
&I = DFWNEXT()
&I = DWFCLOSE()
endsub

sub 'registroExcluido'
&FileNameE = "ARCHIVOEXCLUIDO.ASC" //Nombre que tendra el archivo de texto
&FileNameEPath = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &FileNameE //El archivo se guardara en el directorio de archivos temporales de windows
&I = DFWOPEN(&FileNameEPath, "", "", 1, "")
&I = DFWPTXT(&RegistrosE)
&I = DFWNEXT()
&I = DWFCLOSE()
endsub

sub 'descargarArchivoIncluido'
Descarga.Call(&FileNameI, &FileNameIPath) //Invocar el procedimiento http protocol para descargar el archivo. El mismo se guardara en la carpeta de descargas de windows
endsub

sub 'descargarArchivoExcluido'
Descarga.Call(&FileNameE, &FileNameEPath) //Invocar el procedimiento http protocol para descargar el archivo. El mismo se guardara en la carpeta de descargas de windows
endsub


//PROCEDIMIENTO DE HTTP PROTOCOL
//ATRIBUTOS:
//MAIN PROGRAM = TRUE
//CALL PROTOCOL = HTTP
RULES:
PARM(IN: &FILENAME, &FILENAMEPATH);

SOURCE:
&contentType = 'application/x-download'
&httpResponse.AddHeader('Content-Type', &contentType)
&httpResponse.AddHeader('Content-Disposition', !"attachment;filename="+&FILENAME) //Nombre que le asigna al archivo a ser descargado
&httpResponse.AddFile(&FILENAMEPATH) //Ruta donde esta alojado el documento y lo descarga a la carpeta de descargas de windows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucha prueba y error me di cuenta que por la forma en que un procedimiento definido con los atributos:

**MAIN PROGRAM = TRUE**

**CALL PROTOCOL = HTTP**

este solamente será invocado una sola vez al terminar de ejecutarse todos los eventos del web panel. Lastimosamente significa que no se puede invocar a necesidad, por lo que tuve que modificar el código fuente a solamente devolver un único archivo.

No es exactamente lo que quería lograr, pero se acerca lo suficiente al requerimiento para ser utilizable.